# divisibility of number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I observed that the number of solutions in positive integers $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ of

$$x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$$

for fixed $k$ and $n$ is always a multiple of $k$ as long as $\gcd(k,n)=1$. For example,

$$6=2+1+1+1+1,$$
$$6=1+2+1+1+1,$$
$$6=1+1+2+1+1,$$
$$6=1+1+1+2+1,$$
$$6=1+1+1+1+2,$$

i.e. there are $5$ solutions. Is there any combinatorial rationale behind this? (i.e. combinatorial argument, e.g., via bars and stars?)

Comment: Given a partition of $n$ into $k$ parts, there are $\binom{k}{x_1,\ldots x_n}$ ways to permute that partition. In your case, $k$ is prime, so each multinomial coefficient is divisible by $k$, and thus so is the number of solutions.

Comment: $k$ is not (necessarily) prime.

Comment: Right, I don't immediately have an argument for general $k$.

Comment: But still thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of all positive solutions of the equation 
$x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1}=n$. We show by a combinatorial argument, without even counting $S$, that if $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $k$ divides the number of elements of $S$.

We will say that two elements of $S$ belong to **the same family** if one is a cyclic permutation of the other. We show that if $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then each family has $k$ distinct members. From this it follows that $k$ divides the number of solutions.

So we need to show that a non-trivial cyclic permutation of a solution yields a **different** solution. Let $A=(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{k-1})$ be a solution, and consider the solution $A_t=(a_t,a_{t+1}, \dots, a_{t+k-1})$, where the indices are reduced modulo $k$.

Suppose that for some $t$, with $1\le t\le k-1$, we have $A_t=A$. Then there is a smallest such $t$, and this $t$ divides $k$. Let $k=dt$. If $k\ne 1$, we have $d\gt 1$.

Since $A_t=A$, we have $n=d(a_0+\cdots+a_{t-1})$. It follows that $d$ divides $n$, contradicting the fact that $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

**Remark:** To visualize, imagine the numbers $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{k-1}$ written around a circle. Two solutions belong to the same family if one can be obtained from the other by a rotation.

Comment: That's a very good solution, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This is basically a group-theoretic (or number-theoretic) solution, with the group theory not explicitly mentioned. Group theory comes up quite naturally when we are counting "necklaces" (arrangements of beads, or numbers) around a circle, and we think of arrangements as "the same" if one is a cyclic permutation of the other. Then in counting we have to worry about symmetries. This leads to the Burnside Lemma, and the Polya theory of counting. Everything is connected to everything else!

Answer (score 1):

The [stars-and-bars argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) gives us the formula $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ for the number of positive solutions.

Comparison of this with the formula for $\binom{n}{k}$ shows that if gcd$(n,k)= 1$, then we must have $k$ dividing $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$:

$$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1} $$

Comment: Yes, ok, that's good (actually I knew this before but didn't want to include it in the question). Still, is there a direct way, without recurse to binomial coefficient properties?

Comment: Have a look at [this previous Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320016/an-alternative-approach-to-finding-the-number-of-integer-solutions-of-x-1-cdot), which effectively asks us to reimagine the stars-and-bars argument emphasizing the selection of $k$ out of $n$ dots and multiplying by a "validity" factor $k/n$.  So it could be construed as a purely combinatorial argument.  It's just more concise to state in terms of the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Ok. Plus, I like Rosser's trick :D

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in the number of ordered partitions (a.ka. compositions) of $n$ into $k$ parts. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions

It tells that this number is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$.

So you study divisibility of these numbers.

Comment: Same comment as to hardmath's answer.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that if $\gcd(n,k)=1$ then all the $k$ cyclic $k$-shifts of a solution are different. This means that the number of solutions is divisible by $k$.